# How to correct the error, A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected, when used with SELECTCOLUMNS in DAX

Tags: dax

I have a table **1- Invoices report** that looks like this:

| Invoice Number | Customer Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cus1 |
| 2 | cus2 |
| 3 | cus3 |
| 4 | cus4 |
| ... | ... |

I want to make a column that has only the Customer Number.

I have used the following Expression:

```
Invoice Customers Number = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    '1- Invoices report',
    "Customer Number",
    '1- Invoices report'[Customer  Number]
)
```

With this I am getting the error **A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.**

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of **SELECTCOLUMNS()** is a table, not a column.
Make sure to use it as a **calculated table**, not a **calculated column** or **measure**:

[image]